# Robust Standard Errors as Remedy for Violation of Assumptions in Multi-Level Model

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, assumptions, robust-standard-error

So I ran a multi-level model using the nlme/lme4 R packages. Testing the assumptions, I found that level 1 as well as level 2 residuals are not normally distributed, also there's heteroscedasticity on level 1 and 2. Additionally, level 1 and level 2 residuals are not independent from each other.

I did some research on the topic and found some papers looking at these violated assumptions individually, suggesting robust standard errors should be estimated.

Now my question is: can I actually account for all of these violated assumptions by estimating robust standard errors? This solution seems far too easy for me.

Also I found that often it is suggested that there should at least be 50 level 2 units in order to accurately estimate robust standard errors. Now my sample only consists of 4 measurements nested within 35 individuals (repeated measures). As the estimated robust coefficients will therefore probably also be inaccurate, should I even calculate them? And then report both? Or are those still better than my 'normal' standard errors?

Any input on the matter would be highly appreciated!

This is the model I ran:

```
random_slopes <- lme(DV ~ A_Dummy + B_Dummy + C_mean_centered + 
                      D_mean_centered + E_mean_centered +
                      F_mean_centered, data=data, 
                      random= ~ A_Dummy + B_Dummy + C_mean_centered |ID,
                      method="ML",
                      na.action = na.omit, 
                      control = lmeControl(msMaxIter = 1000000, msMaxEval = 1000000), 
                      correlation = corRatio(form = ~ A_Dummy + B_Dummy |ID))
summary(random_slopes)
```

Edit: added the model equation.

Comment: If you add the equation for your model, it will help readers understand better.